# erro SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined,

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um problemas a algum tempo com um cadastro feito em ajax mas que ao tentar cadastrar usuário cliente na tabela cliente da um erro de sql informando que falta um parâmetro

Já tentei varias maneiras.Entendo que esse parâmetro que a query quer é o id da tabela ,que é mandado no índice 0 do array `$dados`, como posso fazer com que o índice 0 não seja incluído na query?

Estou mandando o meu código inteiro pra ver se alguém puder me ajudar a conexão esta ok, o ajax esta ok o problema esta na pagina crud.php.

```
$(function(){
    //GERAIS
    var errmsg  = $('.msg');
    var forms   = $('form');
    var botao   = $('.j_buttom');
    var urlpost = 'php/crud.php';

    botao.attr("type","submit");

    forms.submit(function(){
        errmsg.fadeOut("fast");
        return false;
    });

    function carregando(){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="load"><img src="img/load.gif" alt="Carregando..."> Aguarde, enviando requisição!</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    function errosend(){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="erro"><strong>Erro inesperado,</strong> Favor contate o admin!</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    //GENÉRICAS
    function errdados( mensagem ){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="erro">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    function sucesso( mensagem ){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="accept">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        url:    urlpost,
        type:   'POST',
        beforeSend: carregando,
        error:      errosend
    });

    //CADASTRO
    var cadastro = $('form[name="cadastro"');

    cadastro.submit(function(){
        var dados = $(this).serialize();
        var acao = "&acao=cadastro";
        var sender  = dados+acao;

        $.ajax({
            data:   sender,
            success: function( resposta ){
                    if(resposta == '1'){
                    errdados('<strong>Erro ao cadastrar:</strong> Existem campos em branco!');
                }else if(resposta == '2'){
                    errosend();
                }else{
                    sucesso( 'Parabéns <strong>'+resposta+'</strong>, seu cadastro foi realizado!' );
                }               
            },

        });
    });

});
```

Conexão com o banco de dados

```
function conectar() {
    define("HOST", "localhost");
    define("BD", "db_clientes");
    define("USER", "root");
    define("PASS", "");

    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".BD;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
    }

    return $pdo;
}
```

---

```
require 'conexao.php';

switch ($_POST['acao']) {
  case 'cadastro':

    $c['nome'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']));
    $c['sobrenome'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['sobrenome']));
    $c['email'] = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $c['telefone'] = filter_var($_POST["telefone"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $c['senha'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['senha']));
    $c['data_cadastro'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if (in_array('', $c)) {
      echo '1';
    } else {

      $dados = array(
        1 => $c['nome'],
        2 => $c['sobrenome'],
        3 => $c['email'],
        4 => $c['telefone'],
        5 => $c['senha'],
        6 => $c['data_cadastro'],

      );

      $Fields = implode(',  ', array_keys($c));
      $values = ':'.implode(' , :', array_keys($c));
      try {

        $cadastra = conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes  ({$Fields})  VALUES ({$values})");
        $cadastra->execute($dados);

        if ($cadastrar->rowCount() == 1) {
          echo $c['nome'].' '.$c['sobrenome'];
        } else {
          echo '2';
        }
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
    break;
  default:
    echo 'Erro ao selecionar ação!';
}
```

Comment: Você está passando os valores na consulta da forma :nome, :email e etc. Para se usar isso no PDO, você deve usar  bindValue e não passar array no método execute.
Veja este link : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php


Você pode usar PDOBindArray($cadastra,$dados); e em seguida chamar o execute sem a passagem de parâmetros

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro esta na passagem do array dados:

```
$dados = array(
   1 => $c['nome'],
   2 => $c['sobrenome'],
   3 => $c['email'],
   4 => $c['telefone'],
   5 => $c['senha'],
   6 => $c['data_cadastro'],
);
```

Basta alterar para:

```
$dados = array(
  ":nome" => $c['nome'],
  ":sobrenome" => $c['sobrenome'],
  ":email" => $c['email'],
  ":telefone" => $c['telefone'],
  ":senha" => $c['senha'],
  ":data_cadastro" => $c['data_cadastro'],
);
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs, tome cuidado com a linha

```
$cadastra->execute($dados);
if ($cadastrar->rowCount() == 1) {
```

`$cadastra` e não `$cadastrar`

Comment: obrigado parece uma coisa tao simples e eu8 ralando aki!!

Comment: Porque falou pra tomar cuidado , estou começando agora no php e preciso de refencia , todo conselho é bem vindo  :)

Comment: valeu  aquele abraço, estava muito frustrado com esse erro pois tentei um monte de coisas.